# convert string to date in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have this date format in hive: 20180618151752

Make the following query to leave it in the following way:

```
select
concat(substr(xdr.time_stop,1,8),' ',
substr(xdr.time_stop,9,2),':',
substr(xdr.time_stop,10,2),':',
substr(xdr.time_stop,11,2)) as date
from padl.fraude_vozm_xdr;
```

20180618 18:17:52

Now, I need to convert that string field to date, how could I do it?.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180618151752','yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss')
```